# Inventory/Recipe Software

Tags: database, inventory

I am looking for software that I can use to track inventory of supplies, and also keep a record of the recipe/requirements for various projects so the system can tell me what all can be made and how many from current inventory.

Comment: Your question is a little too vague for people to advise correctly. Can you give more information? How large is your inventory? Unique items or nor? Need to manage barcodes? Should the software be online or a standalone? Need warnings when the stock becomes low?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do it, If you are doing on small scale i would suggest an excel available at
https://www.tradegecko.com/blog/5-best-ways-to-manage-inventory-in-excel

If you are doing it on an enterprise level and want to use an App, Square provides better tool
https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5228-inventory-management

Answer (score 0):

For those speaking French, and especially for companies located in France, one solution is OpenConcerto: https://www.openconcerto.org

PROS

It is free and open source (written in Java)

- Polished interface
- Standalone (your data are not in the cloud and you don't need a web browser)
- A client-server version exists, which uses a PostgreSQL database. The client-server version is more difficult to install, than the standalone, but I could however install it successfully.
- If I remember well, invoices templates, should be customizable (LibreOffice documents or so, but this would be to confirm.)

CONS

- Very oriented for France and with its administrative and legal aspects in mind.
  This means that when you are not in France, some features of the software can be very boring. For instance, it will always ask a VAT rate.
- Almost impossible to customize, unless you are a confirmed Java programmer. The community is small and the company that develops the software is partly living from custom developments. Although the software is open source, don't expect much help (unless paid help from the developpers) if you need to customize it.

I liked the inventory part but felt that customization would be a long and difficult way for other parts of the software. (Although it's a long road I'm currently developping my own solution for more flexibility.)